# Word 2013 crashes when I attempt to print

Tags: printing, crash, microsoft-office-2013, microsoft-word-2013

I am having issues with MS Word 2013 crashing when I try to print something at my school. The reason I say only at my school is because it appear to work at my home where I have a HP Deskjet printer. The school has HP LaserJets (4250 I think).

I am kind of lost with this one. One recommendation I was told was to disable background printing... that is did not fix anything. I am 99% sure my Anti-Virus can be ruled out for Word (has major issue with Outlook 2013) I am running ESET NOD32 Anti-Virus 6.

I attempted to update my printer driver since the school pushes a driver out from their server. But for some reason I am not able to change the driver my laptop will use, its greyed out. So either they are restricting something or I am not doing it right.

So... Other than the above I am out of idea and hoping someone can give me a clue. I am trying to avoid calling MS support at all costs since they will probably provide no help at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: re-install the school's printer driver again, and set it as default, if it will be carshed again, try to print your paper over network.

Comment: I sort of already tried that. The problem is there are around 13 printers and all of them are the same but some reason when I go to each printer it wants to install the driver again. I removed all the printers (not sure about the actual drivers). Then re-added the printers and I got one good print from it then after that it crashes again.

Comment: what about your ms-word? try to repair or reinstall taht !

Comment: No... don't mess with installing or repairing word, it's probably the driver.

Comment: Have you tried switching your default printer, not through word but through the control panel?

Comment: @ekaj Yeah I tried that. I honestly did not that word had its own default printer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a know issue with the HP drivers.

In the printer driver go to Device settings -> Installable options -> Printer Status notification and select disable.

Ref
[Hp Drivers and Office 2013](http://www.techieshelp.com/office-2013-crashes-when-printing-to-hp-printers/)

Answer (score 0):

Word 2013 was crashing on me when trying to print to an HP Printer in Windows 7.  I set Word 2013 to run in compatibility mode and it resolved my crashing issues.

Right click on Word 2013, Click Properties, Click Compatibility tab, check Run this Program in compatibility mode for, then click the drop down box and choose Windows xp service pack 2

Answer (score 0):

My MS-Word was crashing as soon I was pressing the Print button. I solved the problem by going to my Programs and features and removing a program called STATNOVAPDF which I had no idea what it was. I suggest you go there and scroll down the list and try to find programs that don't seem useful or that could cause problem. Hope this helps.